# Open collector and drain circuits

Tags: digital-logic

I'm learning about circuits and came across open collector and drain logic circuits, I wanted to ask...

1. What are the benefits of open drain/collector circuits?
2. In which logic circuits are they used?
3. Are they used for logic gates?

Comment: Benefits over what other kind of?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open collector/drain outputs can be used to:

- shift a voltage level

Here's an example of a voltage level switching inverter. The input voltages (0 = 0 V, 1 = 1.8 V) can be different from the output voltages (0 = 0 V, 1 = 5 V).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f23vW3.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- combine (OR) a couple of outputs

Here's an example: this circuit combines (ORs) a, b and c and outputs NOT( a OR b OR c). This is for example useful if I have 3 separate ICs which all have an open drain output which becomes activated when the IC is on. Suppose I want to know when all ICs are off, then I could use this circuit. As soon as any of the ICs becomes active, out will be pulled low. Only when out = 1 (supply voltage) there is no IC active.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2W48o.png)</sup>